# Does every covariant functor on module category preserve inclusion?

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, functors

Does every covariant functor $F : ~_R\mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ on module category $_R\mathcal{M}$ preserve inclusion? I have proceeded in the following way.

Suppose $A \subseteq B$ in $_R\mathcal{M}$ then the natural inclusion map $i$ acts as an identity $1_A$ on $A$, then $F(i)$ must act as an identity on $F(A)$, therefore $F(A) \subseteq F(B)$.
But clearly the functor $\mathbb{Z}_n \otimes_\mathbb{Z} -$ doesnot preserve the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$. Am I overlooking something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say it "acts as an identity on $A$". Or more precisely, it does, but that has no reason to be preserved by a functor

Comment: @Max But the inclusion map $i$ works as the identity map $1_A$ on $A$, and by the definition of functor  $F(1_A) = 1_{F(A)}$ therefore $F(i) : F(A) \rightarrow F(B)$ acts as identity map on $F(A)$. Isn't it?

Comment: Please do not post a question simultaneously on MathSE and MathOverflow. In this case, I think this site is more appropriate than MO, so I would advise you to delete the MO version and keep this question.

Comment: See also [this Math Meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo) and [this MO Meta post](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se) on the topic.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thank you for the suggestion. I was unaware of such fact. I have deleted the MO version.

Comment: $F(1_A) = 1_{F(A)}$ is true but that doesn't imply "working on $A$ as the identity" is preserved under $F$, because "working on $A$ as the identity" is about evaluating certain arrows on certain elements, which makes no sense categorically. Try to write out a formal proof of what you are saying (that is, without using intuitive words such as "acts as the identity") and you'll see that you are unable to do so